# How to size android layout dynamically

Tags: android

I need to size the top-most layout of my application dynamically (programmatically) based on information loaded from a configuration file.

Right now the in main.xml I have

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout   
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:background="@drawable/background">
    </LinearLayout>
```

So I am looking for a way to change android:layout_width and layout_height programmatically.

Any help would be appreciated

RM

EDIT:

As per suggestions I have tried the following:

```
LinearLayout l2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout07);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);
l2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But that gives me the following error when running:

```
Thread [<3> main] (Suspended (exception ClassCastException))    
FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 288 
FrameLayout(View).layout(int, int, int, int) line: 6133 
....
```

Comment: Check this out
http://d.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

Comment: I tried that but i think im doing somthing wrong .. ill post more code

Answer (score 3):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,1);


layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Where layout is your LinearLayout fetched with findViewById. Parameters for the width and height are fill_parent in my example with weight 1.

Instead of fill_parent options you can of course use the fixed size in pixels, or omit the weight if you don't want it.

Comment: thats what iv been trying to do, but the application crashes when i add this code ...
this is the last two lines of stack:
(Suspended (exception ClassCastException)) 
FrameLayout.onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int) line: 288

Comment: maybe the weight is doing something weird to the components inside. Can you try again but without the last parameter (without the 1 at the end). Try also adding the size in pixels instead of fill_parent.. Does the same error appear?

Answer (score 0):

I detected a mistake when you try to get your `LinearLayout`. You write it as `LinearLayout07` instead of `LinearLayout01`.